# issue loading mobile widgets with dojo mobile and phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, dojo

I developed a form that should be running on an android device using phonegap and dojo mobile html5 so the page is runing with no issues but when I tested the page on my mobile I encountred some errors.

```
<div id="settings" dojoType="dojox.mobile.View" selected="true">

    <!-- a sample heading -->
    <h1 dojoType="dojox.mobile.Heading">Authentification</h1>
    <form id="loginForm">
        <div class="field-title">Login</div>
        <div class="fieldset">
            <div class="field-row">
                <span>Username*</span><input dojoType="dojox.mobile.app.TextBox" />
            </div>
            <div class="field-row">
                <span>Password*</span> <input type=password name="pass"
                    dojoType="dojox.mobile.app.TextBox"> </input>

            </div>
            <a class="link" href="#">New account</a><a class="link"href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
            <div style="text-align: center;">

            <button dojotype="dojox.mobile.Button" class="mblButton greyBtn baseBtn normalBtn">Connect</button>
                <button id="resetBtn" type=reset dojotype="dojox.mobile.Button"
                    class="mblButton greyBtn baseBtn normalBtn">Reset</button>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

> 04-26 00:11:28.909: D/PhoneGapLog(3029): failed loading
>   dojo/../dojox/mobile/app/TextBox.js with error: Error: Could not load
>   'dojox.mobile.app._Widget'; last tried
>   '../dojox/mobile/app/_Widget.js'
>
> 04-26 00:11:28.909: D/PhoneGapLog(3029): : Line -2167 : failed loading
>   dojo/../dojox/mobile/app/TextBox.js with error: Error: Could not load
>   'dojox.mobile.app._Widget'; last tried '../dojox/mobile/app/_Widget.js
>
> 04-26 00:11:28.909: E/Web Console(3029): failed loading
>   dojo/../dojox/mobile/app/TextBox.js with error: Error: Could not load
>   'dojox.mobile.app._Widget'; last tried
>   '../dojox/mobile/app/_Widget.js' at :-2167

Answer (score 0):

You are running into this problem:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24067

The best thing to do is to fully build Dojo Mobile into a single file when you are building an Android app.